# Is having many iconic features more common in artificial languages?

Tags: sign-languages, conlang

Is there any reason why the iconic nature of signed languages would historically have made linguists consider them to be artificial languages?

Comment: Given that most signed languages only came into existence in the past few centuries, defining "artificial" vs "natural" is somewhat harder than with spoken languages. Nicaraguan Sign Language famously arose pretty much ex nihilo less than fifty years ago, but it has fluent L1 speakers. Would you call that artificial or natural?

Comment: The subject and body of this question appear to ask (slightly) different things

Comment: That's normal, don't you think? Most people don't know how to talk about language, but if they give examples, ...

Answer (score 3):

Etymologically speaking, "artificial" essentially means "deliberately created", as contrasted with "natural" which is that which "just happens". Art is artificial, a beautiful lake is natural. Natural languages "just happened", but artificial languages had to be created by someone thinking about how a language might be. There are some negative connotations assigned to the word "artificial", for which reason contemporary linguists would probably not say that signed languages are "artificial". In fact, in the modern era, "artificial language" is only used to refer to limited fake languages constructed for psycholinguistic experiments. Instead, we speak of constructed languages and manual languages.

Comment: Isn't Nicaraguan Sign Language natural,  at least to the extent it wasn't deliberately created?

Comment: Probably. It certainly calls into question the legitimacy of the natural / artificial distinction, as does pidgin-creation.